# Elastic-search queries in Java: Contains-String query?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I  work in Java with Elastic-search and want to filter data by "contains string" parameter.

For example: retrieve a list of children whose names start with 'r'.

But search query (code below) returns the list of children with names equal (not contains) to 'r'.

I've tried "r*" - no luck.

```
  builder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("r*")
                .field("child_name")
                .lenient(true)
                .escape(true)
                .analyzeWildcard(false)
                .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                .boost(2.0f));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try another type of `QueryBuilder` - `WildcardQueryBuilder`:

> Implements the wildcard search query. Supported wildcards are *, which
>   matches any character sequence (including the empty one), and ?, which
>   matches any single character. Note this query can be slow, as it needs
>   to iterate over many terms. In order to prevent extremely slow
>   WildcardQueries, a Wildcard term should not start with one of the
>   wildcards * or ?.

Example:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("user", "k?mc*");
```

Comment: Hi

My problem was the .analyzeWildcard(false) and the  boost(2.0f));
I changed it and now it is OK, but thanks and vote-up.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem by me-self.
My problems were two:

```
.analyzeWildcard(false)
.boost(2.0f))
```

I change to:

```
.analyzeWildcard(true)
.boost(1.0f))
```

And it helped.

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

[image]

wildcardQuery ==> some function of LIKE in database